# Let $f:A \to B$. Show that if $X \subseteq A$, then $X \subseteq f^{-1}(f(X))$.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $f:A \to B$. Show that if $X \subseteq A$, then $X \subseteq f^{-1}(f(X))$.

I'm confused by this. Since $f^{-1}(f(X)) =\{a \in A : f(a) \in f(X)\}$ and $f(X) = \{f(x) : x \in X\}$ by definition, wouldn't $X = f^{-1}(f(X))$? It's like saying "the set of everything in $A$ that maps into $f(X)$." That would just be $X$ right? I know we would have the conclusion still in that case, but am I missing something?

Comment: There might be 'more' things outside of $X$ that get mapped to $f(X)$ as well.

Comment: Ahhhh dang you are so right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x \in X \subseteq A$. We have $f(x) \in f(X)$. By definition $f^{-1}((f(X)) = \{a \in A : f(a) \in f(X)\}$. Thus, $x \in f^{-1}((f(X))$ and $X \subseteq f^{-1}((f(X))$.